# DataGridTemplateColumn Multiple Column Sorting XAML

Tags: xaml, multiple-columns, datagridtemplatecolumn, columnsorting

I'm trying to allow multiple column sorting on my three columns. When you click the header, the sort button pops up but nothing happens.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="currencydatagrid" GridLinesVisibility="All" CanUserSortColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Currency}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="currencyUserName" Header="User Name" Width=".34*" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="." >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding currencyUser.Text}" Uid="{Binding currencyUser.Uid}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to edit user currency." MouseLeftButtonDown="tb_MouseLeftButtonDown9" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="currencyAmount" Header="Currency Amount" Width=".33*" SortMemberPath="." CanUserSort="True" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding currencyAmount.Text}" Uid="{Binding currencyAmount.Uid}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to edit user currency." MouseLeftButtonDown="tb_MouseLeftButtonDown9" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="currencyTime" Header="Minutes Spent" Width=".33*" SortMemberPath="." CanUserSort="True" >
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding currencyTime.Text}" Uid="{Binding currencyTime.Uid}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to edit user currency." MouseLeftButtonDown="tb_MouseLeftButtonDown9" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```